# 2D array chess board

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I'm trying to make a chess-like design into a console using 2D arrays.
I made borders with "|" and "-" to design a playfield.
However, I have trouble with switching colors of the field ( white | black | white)
Here's my code (without the changing of colors on the numbered fields)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int[,] array2 = new int[6, 9];

        for(int i = 0;i < array2.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (i == array2.GetLength(0)-1 || i == 0)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < array2.GetLength(1); h++)
                    decidingColors(false);
                    Console.Write("|" + "-");
            }
            else
            for (int x = 0;x < array2.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                    decidingColors(false);
                Console.Write("|");
                    decidingColors(true);
                Console.Write(array2[i, x]);

            }
            decidingColors(false);
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void decidingColors(bool wentThrough)
    {
        if(wentThrough == true)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }

    }
}
```

I tried using different methods but it always got somehow into the code and broke it. Do you have a good solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I usually like making custom class for each square on the board.  The square can contain lot of information including the piece on the square.  It will make the code a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set alternate by using x % 2 == 0 to determine odd or even element where needed.

```
for (int x = 0;x < array2.GetLength(1); x++)
{
    decidingColors(false);
    Console.Write("|");
    decidingColors(x % 2 == 0);
    Console.Write(array2[i, x]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your looping may not be printing exactly what you think it is printing.  You should add curly braces to your loop with index `h` so that your indentation matches the actual logic.

```
for (int h = 0; h < array2.GetLength(1); h++) { 
   decidingColors(false);
   Console.Write("|" + "-");
}
```

Comment: It slipped out when I was changing something, already fixed. Thank you